# Replace dates of many columns with 1 and NA with 0

Tags: r, dplyr

There are many columns here, and I need to replace the dates with 1 and NA with 0.  I would like a dplyr solution.  thank you.

```
df <- data.frame(
  id = c(1,2,3),
  diabetes = c("12-12-2007",NA,"2-12-2018"),
  lipids = c(NA,NA,"12-12-2015"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE

)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df %>% mutate(across(-id, ~ifelse(is.na(.), 0, 1)))

  id diabetes lipids
1  1        1      0
2  2        0      0
3  3        1      1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do  :

```
df[-1] <- +(!is.na(df[-1]))
df

#  id diabetes lipids
#1  1        1      0
#2  2        0      0
#3  3        1      1
```